# Need help with table references

Tags: tables

I'm currently using the `aastex` package and I'm having a problem with the `\deluxetable` environment.

Here's what I want to do:

I would like LaTeX to automatically convert my `\citet{blah}` entries into numerical citations and to then automatically populate `\tablerefs` with the author-year form of the citation. I would also like the counting of these citations to be independent of the rest of the paper, such that each table starts from "1".

I'm currently handling this all "manually" using Excel.

#### LaTeX + Excel method:

1. Sort table columns by citation
2. Copy list of author citations and assign each a number, being careful to assign the same number to repeated citations
3. After removing redundancies, use alphabetized list of citations with newly assigned number in the `\tablerefs`
4. Replace original citation column from table with numerical citations from step 2.

Clearly, this becomes a pain very quickly when there are a) many tables, b) the tables change frequently.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am still something of a TeX noob, so my apologies if I've bungled some of the vernacular.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that illustrates your problem. It should be "standalone" in the sense that community members could copy-and-paste a working (or sometimes no 100%-working) copy of you work and manage it from there. Even code snippets are sometimes hard to work with, since it doesn't give a full context.

Comment: \startdata

GJ~1001~A & LHS~102~A & WDS~J00046-4044~A & $ 00~04~36.46 $ & $ -40~44~02.48 $ & 6 \GJ~1001~B & LHS~102~Ba & WDS~J00046-4044~Ba & $ 00~04~34.84 $ & $ -40~44~05.78 $ & 5 \
\enddata

\tablecomments{\scriptsize blah blah blah}

\tablerefs{\scriptsize 
(1) \citet{Adelman-McCarthy:2009lr}
 (2) \citet{Cutri:2003pd}
 (3) \citet{Faherty:2009gf}
 (4) \citet{Leinert:2000bs}
 (5) \citet{Reid:2006kl}
 (6) \citet{Stauffer:2010pb}}

Comment: In case there is no answer to this question, I'm willing to settle for simply changing the citation style to numerical only within the \deluxetable environment. I'm currently using \bibpunct to set the style globally (it seems this only works when placed within the preamble).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764)! Instead of pasting part of your code in a comment, please consider editing your question to add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764), as Werner suggested.